# Infinite Scroll + Tooltips + callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, tooltip, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement a page with [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com) and add [tooltips](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html) to some items. Infinite scroll works fine, but tooltips only appear on the first page, before adding new items with the scroll. This is the example:

https://stage.superbiajuridico.es/news/

The tooltip is in the small yellow circle, when placing the cursor over it. If you scroll down, in the following pages, the rest of the tooltips are not built, although I'm using the append event to build them each time the page is reloaded.

Apparently the code is very simple and I do not know what I'm doing wrong:

```js
 // TOOLTIPS
// ------------------

var miTootip = $('.tooltip-item');
new Tooltip(miTootip, {
  // options
});

// INFINITE SCROLL
// ------------------

var inf = $('.infinite-scroll-container').infiniteScroll({
  // options
});

inf.on('append.infiniteScroll', function(event, response, path, items) {
    // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK
    new Tooltip(miTootip, {
      // options
    });
  });
```

This is not working. I'have not much experience with JS so I think I'm doing wrong something obvious.

**EDIT: When trying to codepen, I realized that the error is elsewhere. The tooltip only appears in the first item (it does not have to do with infinite-scroll). This is the pen:** https://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/yRGyZW

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your `new Tooltip(miTootip)` takes HtmlElement and replaces with tooltip. So in your `append.infiniteScroll` event's callback you have to add element with class `.tooltip-item`, and then create Tooltip.

**UPD**

You selected `.tooltip-item` and with this element, using Tooltip constructor, created tooltip, just for one item. So, if you want this tooltip for all items, that this tooltip need, you have to do smth like that:

```
inf.on('append.infiniteScroll', function(event, response, path, items) 
   {
    $('.infinite-scroll-container').append('<div class="tooltip-item"></div>')
    const miTooltip = $('.tooltip-item')
    new Tooltip(miTooltip, {
       // options
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean to add element to the DOM? It is done by infinite scroll itself. In the provided example the class is other ('.marca-sj'), but it is alrady added to the DOM before `append` create tooltip. https://stage.superbiajuridico.es/news/

Comment: Comment after your UPD. That `div` with that `class` is appended already by the infinite scroll basic functionality every time next page is loaded. I think that I don't need to append it again with the append event.

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips must to be created iterating the jQuery object with a loop.

```
let myTooltip = $('.tooltip-item');
    myTooltip.each(function(){
      new Tooltip(this, {
      title: "Tooltip",
      trigger: "hover",
    });
})
```